# Converting multiple columns to datetime using iloc or loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure if this is the expected behavior, but below is an example dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01','2020-06-30','A'],
                    ['2020-07-01','2020-12-31','B']],
                        columns = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'field1'])
```

Before I upgraded to pandas version `1.3.4`, I believe I was able to convert column dtypes like this:

```py
df.iloc[:,0:2] = df.iloc[:,0:2].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Although is appears to have converted the columns to datetime,

```
            start_date             end_date field1
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00  2020-06-30 00:00:00      A
1  2020-07-01 00:00:00  2020-12-31 00:00:00      B
```

The dtypes appear to still be objects:

```
start_date    object
end_date      object
field1        object
```

I know I am able to do the same thing using the code below, I am just wondering if this is the intended behavior of both `loc` and `iloc`.

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

```
start_date    datetime64[ns]
end_date      datetime64[ns]
field1                object
```

Comment: @rhug123 I edited your question to add dtypes of the operation that succeeded (and in doing so changed the code format from indented to triple-backticks because I couldn't get two separate code blocks appart with no text betwen with the indent method). I hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is part of the changes introduced in [1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html).

[Try operating inplace when setting values with `loc` and `iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#try-operating-inplace-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc)

> When setting an entire column using `loc` or `iloc`, pandas will try to insert the values into the existing data rather than create an entirely new array.

Meaning that `iloc` and `loc` will try to *not* change the dtype of an array *if* the new array can fit in the existing type:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.2, 2.3], 'B': [3.4, 4.5]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df.loc[:, 'A':'B'] = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.2  3.4
1  2.3  4.5
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
     A    B
0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  4.0
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

---

Conversely:
[Never operate inplace when setting `frame[keys] = values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#never-operate-inplace-when-setting-frame-keys-values):

> When setting multiple columns using `frame[keys] = values` new arrays will replace pre-existing arrays for these keys, which will not be over-written ([GH39510](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39510)). As a result, the columns will retain the dtype(s) of values, never casting to the dtypes of the existing arrays.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.2, 2.3], 'B': [3.4, 4.5]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df[['A', 'B']] = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.2  3.4
1  2.3  4.5
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
A    int64
B    int64
dtype: object
```

---

With these changes in mind, we now have to do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01', '2020-06-30', 'A'],
                   ['2020-07-01', '2020-12-31', 'B']],
                  columns=['start_date', 'end_date', 'field1'])

cols = df.columns[0:2]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
# or
# df[df.columns[0:2]] = df.iloc[:, 0:2].apply(pd.to_datetime)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
  start_date   end_date field1
0 2020-01-01 2020-06-30      A
1 2020-07-01 2020-12-31      B
start_date    datetime64[ns]
end_date      datetime64[ns]
field1                object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I didnt notice this change happen, so thank you for explaining it so well, and im glad I learned something new.

Comment: I remembered the change vaguely from the release, but I hadn't contemplated it in this circumstance. Thank you for the question. Hopefully it can help someone else too, because this is _super_ unintuitive.

Comment: Thank you, very informative! I wasn't aware of the `iloc`/`loc` datatype preservation.